# Is there a way to access a variable from a calling function in python?

Tags: global

I'm unsure if this is possible but I was wondering if there is a way to get a variable from an outer scope without passing it as an argument.

I've played around with `global()` and  `inspect` but i'm having issues trying to get the attribute.

Here's what i'm trying to do:

```py
class Example:
    @staticmethod
    def query(**kwargs):
        print(f.read())


with open(__file__) as f:
    Example.query(foo='bar')
```

Comment: At least show what is the error that you get. And what is get_b()?

Comment: I can't mentally parse what you're trying to do here, let alone anything looking messy. What is `a` that you're calling with the context manager? What is `get_b`? What was the purpose of `as b:`?

Comment: We don't need to see it in full, we need to understand what you're actually trying to do. As it is, it's impossible for me to get a grip on your intentions and adding more code isn't going to help if you can't boil it down to a simplified example

Comment: `c()` needs `return b`

Comment: What outer variable are you trying to get? Do you want to use `b` inside `c()`?

Comment: Presumably, then, you're trying to create a SQLAlchemy session that can be passed around?

Comment: What you have shown: a) is bad, you should pass `s` to the function instead; and b) it works although it is bad.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: cba to be honest. I ask a simple question and lose like 20 rep.

Comment: and the counter keeps decreasing... great...

Comment: It appears you are looking for [dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping_vs._dynamic_scoping) or effect handlers, is that correct? [Thread-local](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data) or [contextvar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after a while of back and forth I have finally found a solution to my issue.

As `Matthias` suggested I use global to find the object, i decided to use inspect to add it myself like so:

Assigning

```
def __enter__(self):
    inspect.stack()[1][0].f_globals["_ExampleName"] = self
```

Retrieving (Fixed)

```
    @staticmethod
    def _find_example():
        stack = inspect.stack()
        for stack_index in range(2, len(stack)):
            stack_globals = inspect.stack()[stack_index][0].f_globals
            if "_ExampleName" in stack_globals.keys():
                return stack_globals["_ExampleName"]
```

This is a bit 'dodgy' as inspect is not ment to be used in a production environment, However works and solves my issue

Answer (score -2):

Here is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you're trying to do.

```
class Example:
    @staticmethod
    def query(**kwargs):
        print(f.read())


with open(__file__) as f:
    Example.query(foo='bar')
```

Works as expected.

Comment: If my code gives you the error "name 's' is not defined" then something is really really wrong.

Comment: `f` is created as a variable on global level. `with` doesn't introduce a new scope, so of course `f` is known in the static method like it would be in an ordinary function.

Answer (score -3):

What you should do is have the `Client` class set a class variable to the current session.

```
class Client:

    last_session = None

    def Session():
        # code that creates new session, in variable s
        Client.last_session = s
        return s

client = Client()
with client.Session as s:
    Example.query(foo=bar)

Class Example:

    @staticmethod
    def query(**kwargs):
        s = Client.last_session
        s.magic_stuff()
```

Comment: Every time you reassign `b`, `c()` will get the latest value.

Comment: It't not clear what you're *really* trying to do. `b` is just a variable. You just have to use the same name when you assign it and when you reference it inside `c()`.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make all the code that uses the database refer to the last session that was opened, without having to pass `s` as a parameter. Is that it?

Comment: How would listing the variables help if you don't know the variable name?

Comment: What if there's more than one of the type?

Comment: `def get_session(): for v in vars: if isinstance(v,Session): return v`

Comment: It's a class variable, shared by all the clients. It holds the last session that was opened by any client.